# Cannot click on Vue Select Box using vue-test-utils

Tags: node.js, webpack, vue.js, mocha.js, vue-test-utils

I can't seem to "click" on [these](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/select) select boxes using vue-test-utils and Vue 2. I am using mocha + webpack.

I am determining this by seeing that the `visible-change` event is never triggered as it should on click. Here is how my spec file is like:

```
...
const wrapper = mount(EntityItem, { propsData });
const selectBox = wrapper.find("el-select");

// I tried these:
selectBox.trigger("click");
selectBox.trigger("click.native");
```

As last resort if this doesn't work, I'd have to manually change the `model` attribute to simulate the component change.

----UPDATE----

When I set up a callback for the click event I see something, but I am unable to "select" anything in this select input component.

Comment: select boxes in the link(element ui) have class `el-select-dropdown` class in order to select them you would need `wrapper.find(".el-select-dropdown").trigger("click")` to trigger click event.

Answer (score 0):

the component you are using does not use `select` input element. In order to simulate selecting an option, you would do something like this.

```
wrapper.findAll('.el-select-dropdown__item').at(1).trigger('click'); // simulates clicking of one of the options
```

if you want to simulate clicking of select element itself(to show the dropdown). you could do the following.

```
 wrapper.find('.el-select-dropdown').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

Whitespace's answer above helped, however also needed to ensure you use

```
await Vue.nextTick()
```

before your expect statement. Like so:

```
wrapper.findAll('.el-select-dropdown__item').at(1).trigger('click');
await Vue.nextTick();
expect(enterResultBtn.is('[disabled]')).toBe(true);
```

This allows the DOM to update it's cycle, more [info here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick)